# Unable to read column types from amazon redshift using psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, types, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I'm trying to access the types of columns in a table in redshift using psycopg2.

I'm doing this by running a simple query on `pg_table_def` like as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_table_def;
```

This returns the traceback:

```
psycopg2.NotSupportedError: Column "schemaname" has unsupported type "name"
```

So it seems like the types of the columns that store schema (and other similar information on further queries) are not supported by psycopg2.

Has anyone run into this issue or a similar one and is aware of a workaround? My primary goal in this is to be able to return the types of columns in the table. For the purposes of what I'm doing, I can't use another postgresql adapter.

Using:

python- 3.6.2

psycopg2- 2.7.4

pandas- 0.17.1

Comment: Do you have permissions to access ALL tables? If not specify the table name in WHERE tablename = 'table_name'. Also, review this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html

Comment: I'm almost completely certain I do but if I didn't why would that cause this error (I'm curious about the thought process because I'm new to Postgres)? Either way, I just ran `SELECT * FROM pg_table_def WHERE tablename = 'table_name'` for a table that I have access to and psycopg2 is throwing the same error.

Comment: Post the schema for the table in your question after an [EDIT] line.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like below, and could return the result back to calling service.

```
cur.execute("select * from pg_table_def where tablename='sales'")

results = cur.fetchall()
for row in results:
    print ("ColumnNanme=>"+row[2] +",DataType=>"+row[3]+",encoding=>"+row[4])
```

Not sure about exception, if all the permissions are fine, then, it should work fine, print something like below.

```
ColumnNanme=>salesid,DataType=>integer,encoding=>lzo
ColumnNanme=>commission,DataType=>numeric(8,2),encoding=>lzo
ColumnNanme=>saledate,DataType=>date,encoding=>lzo
ColumnNanme=>description,DataType=>character varying(255),encoding=>lzo
```